# Smooth vectorized outlines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vectorization

I have taken a raster image and coverted it to a vector file.  It is an Ordnance Survey map which shows field boundaries etc.

As the vector file has been created from the pixelated raster file the lines are very uneven.

Is there a way to tell QGIS to staighten the lines by taking the mid points?

Is that clear. Here are two images.

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would give a try with GRASS tools :

1. I guess the resulting vector layer could be enhanced applying first the [r.thin](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.thin.html) command to your input raster.
2. Then vectorize the raster by running  [r.to.vect](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.to.vect.html) command.